# How to make return in function correctly?

Tags: javascript

```
function checkAnswer(id, answer) {
    answer = answer.trim();
    var xhr = new XmlHttpRequest();
    xhr.open('POST', './c.php', true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            console.log("FROM xhr: "+xhr.responseText);
             return xhr.responseText;
        }
                }
    xhr.send();

}
```

This function can't return in right way. `console.log("FROM xhr: "+xhr.responseText)` is work, but not a `return` statement (return `undefined`). Why?

In `c.php` I have just `echo "OK";`

I also tried to paste `return` statement after `xhr.send()` , but it's also return `undefined`.

Comment: what does `console.log("FROM xhr: "+xhr.responseText);` print ??

Comment: @Ravi, it is print "FROM xhr: OK". Working correctly

Answer (score 0):

Your code execute asynchronous (function do not wait for AJAX response) so your function return `undefined`. Read about [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).